# Dynamic programming: Fibonacci generator

Tags: programming

I have the following piece of code:

```
A[m_, k_] := For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= k, j++,
   A[i_, j_] = If[i <= 0, 0,
     If[[i == 1 || i == 2] && j == 2, 1,
      If[OddQ[i]; j == 1, 1,
       If[! OddQ[i]; j == 1, 0,
        If[j == 2, A[i - 2, 2] + A[i - 3, 2], 
         If[i <= j, Fibonacci[i], 
          False]
         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

When executing `A[2, 3]` I should get an answer that is equal to `Fibonacci[2]`, but it does not work that way. Any suggestions ?

Comment: [Real programmers don't use loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here (and I'm sure there are better ways) but the problem may lie in your usage of i, j both as symbolic patterns in the second definition of A and as variables with values in the outer loop. It might be that removing the underscores in the second definition resolves the problem.

Comment: Actually, what I actually need is solving a recursive formula. Need to perform this without a recursion, for complexity reasons. And thus have this frustrating code. Is there a simple way to do this? (with two cases in the formula)

Comment: @shi So you may post your formula ...

Comment: posted it below... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is the solution:

```
A[m_, k_] := For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= k, j++,
   A[i, j] =
    If[i <= 0, 0, 
     If[(i == 1 || i == 2) && j == 2, 1,
      If[OddQ[i]; j == 1, 1,
       If[! OddQ[i]; j == 1, 0,
        If[j == 2, A[i - 2, 2] + A[i - 3, 2], 
         If[i <= j, Fibonacci[i], 
          False]]]]]]]]
```

I found an error in one of the If statements:

```
[i == 1 || i == 2] && j == 2
```

should be

```
(i == 1 || i == 2) && j == 2
```

I subsequently changed

```
A[i_, j_] =
```

to

```
A[i, j] =
```

in this way, instead of defining the function again, the program is saving the value of whatever A[i,j] is each time.

To visualize this in a grid, the function Grid should do the job.

```
Grid[Table[Table[A[i,j],{i,1,10}],{j,1,10}]]
```

in which the tens can be changed to any number.
And you can also add the optional

```
...Frame -> All]
```

to the Grid function to make it nicer.

Comment: Please, use the comment section just below the answer/question you are trying to respond to. This is strictly answer-only box.

Comment: sorry, first time

Comment: This is the recursive formula I try to solve, not including all stopping conditions. I have plenty stopping condition, as you can see with all the if's above.  A_{m,k} =\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
F_m, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ m\leq k,\cr
%\cr
\sum_{j=m-k}^{m-2} A_{j,k},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ m>k. \cr

Comment: @FrancsecoInsulla No worries :)

Comment: I fixed it, do you want me to put the code? I'll explain too

Comment: sure, thank you!

Comment: did it fix your problem?

Comment: yes, thank you very much! but it's a little slow. Is this because of the implementation of the Fibonacci function or because of all those loops?

Comment: the Fibonacci function is pretty fast, it's probably because of the loops and all the if statements

Comment: Thanks. How can I enter this data calculated into a table, the moment it is calculated, which might have a better runtime?

Comment: as soon as it is calculated, A of whatever i and j are is saved, because I put A[i,j]=... , this means that putting them into a table will not help.

Comment: so I can print the whole A table?

Comment: I'm not very good with optimization...

Comment: ok thank you very much!

Comment: Grid[Table[Table[A[j, i], {i, 1, 10}], {j, 1, 2}], Frame -> All] should work, changed the 10 and 2

Comment: @FrancsecoInsulla - your post has been flagged as "not an answer" by several users. But having reviewed it and the subsequent comments, I think you are on your way to having an answer. Please edit your post to incorporate some of the additional information you provided in comments, with a bit more explanation.

Comment: I tried to fix it, thanks